# Extracting an attribute value from div with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to extract the content of a attribute in a specific div tag on a webpage. But the attribute contains a list a values. How can i reach the value?

The Value i need the "999999999" from **importantvalue**

The specific div is:

```
<div class="1234" data-component="aaaaa" data-settings='{"baseURL": "https://someurl.com/","importantvalue": "999999999"}'>
```

I use the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(div)


getDiv = soup.find("div", {"class": "1234"})
print(getDiv.attrs['data-settings'])
```

My output is:

```
{"baseURL": "https://someurl.com/","importantvalue": "999999999"}
```

How can i reach the "importantvalue" now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the data inside the attribute can be parsed with [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html) module:

```
txt = '''<div class="1234" data-component="aaaaa" data-settings='{"baseURL": "https://someurl.com/","importantvalue": "999999999"}'>'''

import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

data = json.loads( soup.div['data-settings'] )
print(data['importantvalue'])
```

Prints:

```
999999999
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), you can access a tag’s attributes by treating the tag like a **dictionary**.

Therefore, this would be sufficient:

```
print(getDiv.attrs['data-settings']['importantvalue'])
```